# Need to extract the product details randomly using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

[image]

I need to get the Product details randomly on the attached image using Jmeter request.

Help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Where are you extracting it from? Is this from JAVA? Perhaps a HTML page? The answer to your question will be different depending on where it comes from.

Comment: From the Json response @radimpe

Comment: In that case, add an example of the JSON response that represents the above image and we can try and help you get to a solution. Also helps if you can show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Try these two links and see if you can work it out yourself. Then ask specific questions about where you get stuck: https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/ and https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/12/parsing-json-responses-with-jmeter/

Comment: Thanks @radimpe , I have already gone through the links specified above. I got stuck at navigating to sub categories . I need to look at the below condition based on the below:

IF (CATEGORY HAS SUB CATEGORY)
 GET SUB CATEGORY ID
 IF (SUB CATEGORY ID HAS ANOTHER SUB CATEGORY)
GET ANOTHER SUB CATEGORY
 GET PRODUCT ID FROM ANOTHER SUB CATEGORY 
ELSE
GET PRODUCT ID

Comment: @radimpe could you please help me in jmeter for IF-ELSE loop. I hope that would help my problem. I have not seen ELSE in Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) configured like:

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor Example]

Where:

- `product` is a reference name, if extraction will be successful you will be able to refer random product as `${product}` where required
- `$..product.id` - a [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) Expression in order to extract `id` attribute of `product` node (it might not work as I don't have idea how your "Product" objects look like, update your question with full (or partial) JSON response, better as text, not screenshot in order to get working query)
- `0` - indicates random match

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: I need to get the Product id randomly as specified on the image (Initial image )